# Delay in delegate.begininvoke and actual invocation

Tags: c#, asynchronous

There is delay in the `BeginInvoke` and actual invoke of the method.

In my code I call method using `delegate.BeginInvoke` in the for loop and after for loop there is code to wait for all thread to complete.

```
for(count=0;count<4; Count;count++)
{
    MethodDelegatedglt;
    dglt = new MethodDelegate(this.ProcessResponse);

    asyncResult = dglt.BeginInvoke(Param1, null, null);
    wHandle.Add(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle);
}

logMessage( GUIDSessionXML + " Waiting on all threads to complete.", LogLevel.Debug);
```

As you can see in above code delegate is define on line 1 and on line 2 it is assigned.
On line 3 asynchronous call is made and added in waithandle array.

Below I am waiting for the all wait handle to complete

```
if (!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(wHandle, connectionTimeOut, false) )
{
   ...      
}
```

from the log I came to know that method is not called as soon as we call `BeginInvoke`, there is delay.

```
2014-06-20 15:19:42.6104 => Waiting on all threads to complete.
2014-06-20 15:19:44.4044 => Start of ProcessResponse.
```

as you can see above methods is called after nearly 2 sec.

What could be the reason behind this and how it can be fixed, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: There is *always* a delay.  How long it might take entirely depends on how many threads are active in the thread pool.  If you don't want the thread pool scheduler to do its job then you should use a Thread instead of a delegate's BeginInvoke() method.  Which *can* be faster if the thread is doing a lot of waiting for I/O.

Comment: How many threads are you using in the thread-pool? More than the "min threads" setting? Time to use async IO, or raise the limits, or use a custom thread-pool.

Comment: It is async call withiin async call, from main proc i make 5 async call and from those 5 async calls i make another 4 call each (miniumum depends on the result) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread pool can be lazy when creating new threads. A new thread creation can be delayed for up to 500ms (for more details, check Joe Duffy's ["CLR thread pool injection, stuttering problems"](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/07/08/clr-thread-pool-injection-stuttering-problems/)).

To account for this behavior, increase the number of pre-allocated threads with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`.

Most likely, you should re-evaluate the design of your application and consider using some modern technologies of parallel programming: [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info) (including [Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info), [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).